# Сайт грузится и не загружается

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-express

Использую iis express,  проект asp.net mvc4, visual studio community 2015. windows 7

Первый раз запускаю сайт, грузится и переходит на страницу авторизации, как и задумано в маршрутах. Дальше нажимаю кнопку зарегистрировать, страница грузится, и дальше никакого результата, только вечная загрузка, как будто зацикливание.

Останавливаю проект, запускаю заново, и теперь даже бесконечно грузится главная страница.

В гугл хром нажал f12, чтобы посмотреть какие скрипты запускаются. Пусто.

Куда копать? Сам код:

```
public class AuthorizationController : BaseController
    {
        public AuthorizationController()
        {
            ViewBag.IsDisplayTopMenu = false;
            ViewBag.IsNotAutorized = true;
            HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true;
            HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;
        }

        [HttpGet, ActionName("SignUp")]
        public ActionResult SignUpGet()
        {
            SignUpModel model = new SignUpModel();

            var countries = GetCountrySelectList();
            ViewBag.Countries = countries;
            ViewBag.Cities = GetCitiesSelectList(Int32.Parse(countries.First().Value));
            //model.Birthday = DateTime.UtcNow;

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost, ActionName("SignUp")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> SignUpPost(SignUpModel model)
        {
            SelectList tempList;

            // 1 - Валидация
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // 2 - Проверяем на дублирование почты пользователя
                User user = _unitOfWork.UserRepository.Get(x => x.Email.Equals(model.Email) && !x.IsDeleted).SingleOrDefault();

                if (user != null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("user", "Пользователь с таким адресом электронной почты уже зарегистрирован.");
                    model.Password = string.Empty;
                    model.ConfirmPassword = string.Empty;
                    tempList = GetCountrySelectList();
                    ViewBag.Countries = tempList;
                    ViewBag.Cities = GetCitiesSelectList(Int32.Parse(tempList.First().Value));

                    return View(model);
                }

                //DateTime birthday;
                //var isDateValid = DateTime.TryParse(model.Birthday, out birthday);
                //if (!isDateValid) ModelState.AddModelError("Birthday", "Birthday needs to be a valid date.");


                // 3 - Валидация дня рождения
                DateTime currentDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                if (model.Birthday < currentDate.AddYears(-100) || model.Birthday > currentDate.AddYears(-16))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("model.Birthday", "Допустимый возраст пользователей от 16 и старше.");
                    model.Password = string.Empty;
                    model.ConfirmPassword = string.Empty;
                    tempList = GetCountrySelectList();
                    ViewBag.Countries = tempList;
                    ViewBag.Cities = GetCitiesSelectList(Int32.Parse(tempList.First().Value));

                    return View(model);
                }

                // 4 - Шифруем пароль
                String hashedPassword = CryptographyHelper.HashPassword(model.Password);

                // 5 - Генерируем ключ активации
                String activationToken = CryptographyHelper.GenerateActivationToken();

                // 6 - Создаем пользователя и сохраняем его в БД
                User dataUser = new User
                {
                    FirstName = model.FirstName,
                    MiddleName = model.MiddleName,
                    LastName = model.LastName,
                    CountryId = model.CountryId,
                    CityId = model.CityId,
                    Birthday = model.Birthday,
                    CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    Email = model.Email,
                    ConfirmationToken = activationToken,
                    UserPasswordHash = hashedPassword,
                    Gender = (int)model.Gender,
                    Growth = model.Growth,
                    Weight = model.Weight,
                    IsDeleted = false,
                    LastVisitDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    Phone = model.Phone
                };
                _unitOfWork.UserRepository.Insert(dataUser);
                await _unitOfWork.SaveAsync();

                // 7 - Отправляем письмо для подтверждения регистрации
                if (HttpContext.Request.Url != null)
                {
                    ConfirmRegistrationMailMessage mailMessage =
                        new ConfirmRegistrationMailMessage(dataUser, HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
                    await Emailer.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
                }

                return RedirectToAction("RegistrationSuccess");
            }

            tempList = GetCountrySelectList();
            ViewBag.Countries = tempList;
            ViewBag.Cities = GetCitiesSelectList(Int32.Parse(tempList.First().Value));

            model.Password = string.Empty;
            model.ConfirmPassword = string.Empty;
            return View(model);
        }

        public ActionResult RegistrationSuccess()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet, ActionName("SignIn")]
        public ActionResult SignInGet()
        {
            SignInModel model = new SignInModel();

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost, ActionName("SignIn")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult SignInPost(SignInModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var users = _unitOfWork.UserRepository.Get(x => x.Email == model.Email && !x.IsDeleted);
                var user = users.FirstOrDefault();
                if (user == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("user", "Пользователь не найден.");
                    model.Password = string.Empty;
                    return View(model);
                }
                var password = CryptographyHelper.HashPassword(model.Password);
                if (user.UserPasswordHash == password)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Email, true);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "HealthPanel");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (user.UserPasswordHash != password)
                    {
                        model.Password = string.Empty;
                        ModelState.AddModelError("user", "Неверный пароль");
                    }
                }
            }
            model.Password = string.Empty;
            return View(model);

        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult SignOut()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

            return Redirect("signin");
        }
    }
```

**Views**

```
@model Project.Models.Authorization.SignInModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SignIn";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_DefaultLayoutForNonAuthorize.cshtml";
}
<script src="~/Content/scripts/sign-in.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="~/Content/Styles/page-enter.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/Styles/sticky-footer.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="~/Content/Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body class="page-enter-body">

    <!-- Begin page content -->
    <header>
        <div class="page-top-thr-lv">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="top-3 page-enter-top-3">
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-6 page-enter-pull-right">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 logo">
                            <p class="text-center">text </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
                            <a href="/" title=""><img src="~/Content/img/logo.png" alt="" /></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div><!--/.page-top-thr-lv -->
    </header>
    <section class="main-content">
        <div class="container">

    @using (Html.BeginForm("SignIn", "Authorization", FormMethod.Post))
            {
        <div class="col-md-4 padding0 feedback">
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary()
            <div class="form-group col-md-9 padding0">
                <label for="InputEmail">Эл. почта</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { @class = "form-control", id = "InputEmail", placeholder = "example@mail.com" })
                @*<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com" pattern="[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}">*@
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-9 padding0">
                <label for="InputPassword">Пароль</label>
                @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Password, new { @class = "form-control", id = "InputPassword" })
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 marginleft105 padding0">
                    <div class="col-md-12 padding0">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-send">Войти</button>



             }
                        @Html.ActionLink("Зарегистрироваться", "SignUp", "Authorization", new { @class = "btn btn-send" })
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
    </section><!--/.main-content -->
    <div class="bg"></div>
    <div id="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="text-muted">© 2015</p>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

**view signup**

```
using ColorLongLife.Utilities
@model ColorLongLife.Models.Authorization.SignUpModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SignUp";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_DefaultLayoutForNonAuthorize.cshtml";
}

@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Content/scripts/sign-up.js"></script>
@*<script src="~/Content/scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>*@
    <script src="~/Content/scripts/edit-profile.js"></script>
}

<section class="main-content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6 padding0">
            <h1>Регистрация</h1>
            <div class="intro-2">
                <p>Все поля обязательны к заполнению, так как играют важную роль при расшифровке диагностики.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("SignUp", "Authorization", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary()
            <div class="col-md-2 padding0 feedback">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12 padding0">
                    <label for="InputFIO">Фамилия</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName, new { @class = "form-control", id = "InputFIO", placeholder = "Зареченская", type = "text" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-12 padding0">
                    <label for="InputName">Имя</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", id = "InputName", placeholder = "Анна", type = "text" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-12 padding0">
                    <label for="InputSecondName">Отчество</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MiddleName, new { @class = "form-control", id = "InputSecondName", placeholder = "Ивановна", type = "text" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-12 padding0">
                    <label for="InputBirthday">Дата рождения</label>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Birthday, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "InputBirthday" } })
                    @*@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Birthday, "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control", id = "InputBirthday" })*@
                </div>
                <div class="radio1">
                    <p>Пол</p>
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Gender, Gender.Male, new { name = "rbtnGender", id = "optionsRadios2" })
                    <label><span class="cbxGender"></span> Мужской</label>
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Gender, Gender.Female, new { name = "rbtnGender", id = "optionsRadios1" })
                    <label><span class="cbxGender"></span>Женский</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-5 padding0">
                    <label for="weight">Рост (см.)</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Growth, new { @class = "form-control", id = "weight", placeholder = "176" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-5 col-md-offset-2 padding0">
                    <label for="height">Вес (кг.)</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Weight, new { @class = "form-control", id = "height", placeholder = "69" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-12 padding0">
                    <label for="country">Страна проживания</label>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CountryId, ViewBag.Countries as SelectList, "Выберите страну", new { @class = "form-control", id = "country", type = "text" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-12 padding0">
                    <label for="city">Город</label>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CityId, ViewBag.Cities as SelectList, "Выберите город", new { @class = "form-control", id = "city", type = "text" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-12 padding0">
                    <label for="telephone">Телефон</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Phone, new { @class = "form-control", id = "telephone", placeholder = "", type = "text" })
                    <span><img src="~/Content/img/info.png" />для оперативной связи</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-12 padding0">
                    <label for="email">Эл. почта</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { @class = "form-control", id = "email", placeholder = "ekaterina@mail.com", type = "text" })
                    @*<span><img src="~/Content/img/error.png" />Эл. почта не введена</span>*@
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-12 padding0">
                    <div>
                        <label for="password">Пароль</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Password, new { @class = "form-control", id = "password", type = "password" })
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <label for="confirmPassword">Повторите пароль</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control", id = "confirmPassword", type = "password" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 dop paddingleft30">
                <p>Регистрация позволит вам воспользоваться всеми услугами персонального кабинета:</p>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"> </span>Пройти бесплатное цветовое тестирование, выявляющие психологически проблемные области вашей жизни</li>
                    <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"> </span>Ознакомиться с демо-расшифровками результатов тестирования и осмысленно выбрать нужный вид расшифровки для себя</li>
                    <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"> </span>Воспользоваться платными сервисами, которые позволяют выявить влияние психологических проблем на здоровье</li>
                    <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"> </span>Записаться на консультацию к клиническому психологу по результатам расшифровки теста</li>
                    <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"> </span>Купить персональные курсы цветовой коррекции</li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"> </span>Увидеть список полезных для вас биологически активных добавок, которые были подобраны по результатам теста и купить их.
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="secret">text.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="checkbox1 col-md-8 padding0">
                <input type="checkbox" value="" checked>
                <label><span class="cbxUserAgreement"></span>Я прочитал и согласен с <a href="">Пользовательским соглашением</a></label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="" checked>
                <label><span class="cbxRegulationsPersonalData"></span>Я прочитал и согласен с <a href="">Положением о персональных данных</a> </label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="" checked>
                <label><span class="cbxLimitationPprofessionalLiability"></span>Я прочитал и согласен с <a href="">Ограничением профессиональной ответственности</a> </label>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-send">Зарегистрироваться</button>
        }
    </div>
</section><!--/.main-content -->
```

Comment: Сделайте трассировку по шагам, чтобы понять, после какого шага зависает. Скорее всего где-то зацикливание в коде. Либо выкладывайте весь проект, а то сидеть построчно выявлять визуально вручную Вашу ошибку очень тяжело...

Comment: а можно подробнее, что значит трасировка по шагам?

Comment: @StefanHansch если вы хотите, чтобы человек увидел уведомление о ваше комментарии, нужно писать тег в начале (как это сделано у меня).

Comment: "Трассировка по шагам" - означает поставить точку остановки в начале SignInPost и передвигаться по строчке, пока не зависнете (клавиша F10 в VS).

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, зависание происходит при отправке почты. Проверьте timeout на попытку подключиться к SMTP серверу и саму отправку сообщения.